# Find string (from table) in cell in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, find, cell

I want to find the location of one string (which I take it from a table) inside of a cell:
A is my table, and B is the cell.

I have tested :

```
strncmp(A(1,8),B(:,1),1)
```

but it couldn't find the location.
I have tested many commands like:
ismember,strmatch,find(strcmp),find(strcmpi)find(ismember),strfind and etc ... but they all give me errors mostly because of the type of my data !

So please suggest me a solution.

Comment: @BrianTompsett if you're intent on mass-editing questions in a rambo burnination effort (which you often are), I suggest using [a local variant of the meta post with huge support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299728/are-we-still-trying-to-axe-the-table) rather than a years-old-dormant closed post on MSE with a few votes.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for bringing the the other meta-post to my attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
>> strfind('0123abcdefgcde', 'cde')
ans =
     7    12
```

---

If `A` is a table and `B` a cell array, you need to index this way:

```
strfind(B{1}, A.VarName{1});
```

For example:

```
>> A = cell2table({'cde'},'VariableNames',{'VarName'}); %// create A as table
>> B = {'0123abcdefgcde'}; %// create B as cell array of strings
>> strfind(B{1}, A.VarName{1})
ans =
     7    12
```

Answer (score 2):

Luis Mendo's answer is absolotely correct, but I want to add some general information.

Your problem is that all the functions you tried (strfind, ...) only work for normal strings, but not for cell array. The way you index your `A` and `B` in your code snippet they still stay a cell array (of dimension (1,1)). You need to use curly brackets `{}` to "get rid of" the cell array and get the containign string. Luis Mendo shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Modified solution from a Mathworks forum, for the case of a single-column table with ragged strings

```
find(strcmp('mystring',mytable{:,:}))
```

will give you the row number.